# invalid date when adding product with custom options(datetime) using REST API

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php, rest-api

1. I have a product with a custom option DateTime filed in product options
   [image: Screenshot from 2020-10-07 16-59-54]
2. When I try to place an order using rest API.  My order  array is given below

```
$order = array (
  'cartItem' => 
  array (
    'sku' => $product_sku,
    'qty' => 1,
    'quote_id' => $cart_id,
    'product_option' => 
    array (
      'extension_attributes' => 
      array (
        'custom_options' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'option_id' => '1',
            'option_value' => '2020-10-15 13:00:00',
          )
      ),
    ),
  ),
    ),
);
```

3. My cart response is given below

`"{"item_id":4,"sku":"Jessica Pant","qty":1,"name":"Jessica Pant","price":169,"product_type":"simple","quote_id":"3","product_option":{"extension_attributes":{"custom_options":[{"option_id":"1","option_value":"2020-10-16 01:00:00"}]}}}"`

4. As you can see i have set custom option value(datetime) as '**2020-10-15 13:00:00**' in code. But after execute add to cart API code. the date changed to **"2020-10-16 01:00:00"**

#### Expected result (*)

`"{"item_id":4,"sku":"Jessica Pant","qty":1,"name":"Jessica Pant","price":169,"product_type":"simple","quote_id":"3","product_option":{"extension_attributes":{"custom_options":[{"option_id":"1","option_value":"2020-10-15 13:00:00"}]}}}"`

#### Actual result (*)

`"{"item_id":4,"sku":"Jessica Pant","qty":1,"name":"Jessica Pant","price":169,"product_type":"simple","quote_id":"3","product_option":{"extension_attributes":{"custom_options":[{"option_id":"1","option_value":"2020-10-16 01:00:00"}]}}}"`

My  Magento ver. 2.3.4-p2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the issue.
Actually, it was not a core issue of magento2. The issue was related to a settings in  catalog congiuration

```
stores > config > catalog > catalog > Date & Time Custom Options
```

My setting was `12h AM/PM`

I changed it to `24h`

Hope it will help someone :)